# How can I create a more efficient way of parsing words between two large text files (Python 3.6.4)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm brand new to Python and this was my first attempt in applying what I've learned, but I know I'm being inefficient. The code works but it takes a couple minutes to finish executing on a novel sized text file.

Is there a more efficient way to reach the same output? Any styling critiques would also be appreciated. Thank you!

```
def realWords(inFile, dictionary, outFile):
    with open(inFile, 'r') as inf, open(dictionary, 'r') as dictionary, open(outFile, 'w') as outf:
    realWords = ''
    dList = []
    for line in dictionary:
        dSplit = line.split()
        for word in dSplit:
            dList.append(word)
    for line in inf:
        wordSplit = line.split()
        for word in wordSplit:
            if word in dList:
                realWords += word + ' '
    outf.write(realWords)
    print('File of real words created')
    inf.close()
    dictionary.close()
    outf.close()

'''
I created a function to compare the words in a text file to real words taken 
from a reference dictionary (like the Webster Unabridged Dictionary). It 
takes a text file and breaks it up into individual word components. It then 
compares each word to each word in the reference dictionary text file in 
order to test whether the world is a real word or not. This is done so as to 
eliminate non-real words, names, and some other junk. For each word that 
passes the test, each word is then added to the same empty string. Once all 
words have been parsed, the output string containing all real words is 
written to a new text file.
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every single word in your novel, you search the ENTIRE dictionary once to see if you can find that word. That's really slow.

You can benefit from using a set() data structure, with lets you quickly determine, in constant time, whether an element is inside of it or not.

Furthermore, by getting rid of string concatenation and using .join() instead, you can speed your code up some more.

I made some adjustments to your code so it uses set() and .join(), which should speed it up considerably

```
def realWords(inFile, dictionary, outFile):
    with open(inFile, 'r') as inf, open(dictionary, 'r') as dictionary, open(outFile, 'w') as outf:
    realWords = [] #note list for constant time appends
    dList = set()
    for line in dictionary:
        dSplit = line.split()
        for word in dSplit:
        dList.add(word)
    for line in inf:
        wordSplit = line.split()
        for word in wordSplit:
            if word in dList: #done in constant time because dList is a set
                realWords.append(word)
    outf.write(' '.join(realWords))
    print('File of real words created')
    inf.close()
    dictionary.close()
    outf.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set()` to do quick lookup of words, and you can increase the string concatenation speed by using `" ".join(your_list)`, something like:

```
def write_real_words(in_file, dictionary, out_file):
    with open(in_file, 'r') as i, open(dictionary, 'r') as d, open(out_file, 'w') as o:
        dictionary_words = set()
        for l in d:
            dictionary_words |= set(l.split())
        real_words = [word for l in i for word in l.split() if word in dictionary_words]
        o.write(" ".join(real_words))
        print('File of real words created')
```

As for style, the above is mostly PEP-compliant, I've shortened the variable names to avoid scrolls on the code block in SO, I'd suggest you to use something more descriptive for real world usage.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a possible response. The main comments I have are:

1) Modularize the functions more; that is, each function should do fewer things (i.e. should do one thing very well). The function `realWords` can only be reused in the very specific case you want to do *all of exactly what you propose*. The functions below do fewer things, so they are more likely to be reused.

2) I added functionality to remove special chars from words to avoid Type II error (that is, to avoid missing a real word and calling it nonsense)

3) I added functionality to store everything that is designated as not a real word. The main QC step for this workflow would be iteratively examining the output going into the "nonsense" category and systematically eliminating true words that were missed.

4) Store the real words in the dictionary as a `set` in python to guarantee minimal lookup time.

5) I did not run this because I do not have appropriate input files, so I may have a few typos or bugs in there.

```
# real words could be missed if they adjoin a special character. strip all incoming words of special chars
def clean_words_in_line(input_line):
""" iterate through a line, remove special characters, return clean words"""
        chars_to_strip=[":", ";", ",", "."] # add characters as need be to remove them
        for dirty_word in input_line:
                for char in chars_to_strip: 
                        clean_word=dirty_word.strip(char)
                        clean_words.append(dirty_word)
        return(clean_words)

def ref_words_to_set(dct_file):
""" iterate through a source file containing known words, build a list of real words, return as a set """
        clean_word_list=[]
        with open(dct_file, 'r') as dt_fh:
                for line in dt_fh:
                        line=line.strip().split()
                        clean_line=clean_words_in_line(line)
                        for word in clean_line:
                                clean_word_list.append(word)
        clean_word_set=set(clean_word_list) # use a set comprehension to minimize lookup time 
        return(clean_word_set)

def find_real_words(my_novel, cws):
""" iterate through a book or novel, check for clean words """
        words_in_dict=[]
        quite_possibly_runcible=[]
        with open(my_novel) as mn_fh:
                for line in my_novel:
                        line=line.strip().split()
                        clean_line=clean_words_in_line(line)
                        for word in clean_line:
                                if word in cws:
                                        words_in_dict.append(word)
                                else:
                                        quite_possibly_runcible.append(word)
        return(words_in_dict, quite_possibly_runcible)


set_of_real_words=ref_words_to_set("The_Webster_Unabridged_Dictionary.txt")
(real_words, non_sense)=find_real_words("Don_Quixote.txt", set_of_real_words)

with open("Verified_words.txt", 'a') as outF:
        outF.write(" ".join(real_words) + "\n")

with open("Lears_words.txt", 'a') as n_outF:
        n_outF.write(" ".join(non_sense) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for understanding, rather than just giving better code.

What you need to do is study [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

The complexity of reading the dictionary is `O(number of lines in dictionary * number of words per line)`, or just `O(number of words in dictionary)`.

The complexity of reading `inf` *looks* similar at first. However, idiomatic python includes deceptive practices - namely, `if word in dList` is not a constant-time operation for some types. Additionally, the python language requires a new object for `+=` here (although in limited circumstances, it can optimize it out - but don't rely on that), thus the complexity is equal to `O(length of realWords)`. Assuming most words are in fact in the dictionary, this is equivalent to the length of the file.

So your overall complexity for this step is `O(number of words in infile * number of words in dictionary)` with the optimization, or `O((number of words in infile)² * number of words in dictionary)` without it.

Since the complexity of the first step is smaller and smaller components disappear, the overall complexity is just the complexity of the second half.

The other answers give you a complexity of `O(number of words in dictionary + number of words in file)`, which is irreducible since the sides of the + are unrelated. Of course, this assumes no hash collisions, but as long as your dictionary is not subject user input, that's a safe assumption. (If you do, grab the [`blist` package from pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) for a convenient container with good worst-case performance).